# .htaccess - Force SSL and dont show .html in URL

Tags: htaccess, redirects, https

I have a website where i want to Force `https` to all visitors, and I also don't want the URL to show `.html` at the end.

In Google Search Console and Bing Webmaster tool i get an "Redirect errror" when it tries to index my site.

I'm not sure if my code is good or right. I have made this code in the .htaccess-file:

```sh
# Begin
    
RewriteEngine on
    
# Enforce SSL
# Handle non-www URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    
# Handle www URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    
# Handle URLs without .html extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(GET) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1.html [L]
    
#Error Codes
ErrorDocument 403 http://example.com/403.html
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404.html
    
# End
```

Comment: Is something not working when you deploy this .htaccess?

Comment: I forgot to mention. In Google Search Console and Bing Webmaster tool i get an "Redirect errror" when it tries to index my site. I suspect that the issue is in the .htaccess file. Thank you

Comment: What do you get if you test your site yourself?

Comment: What are the details of this "Redirect error"? For what URL(s) are you getting this "Redirect error"? What is the canonical domain? www or non-www?